# How do i append a method to a type?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a class called CountService. It has this method

```
public int count()
```

What I want is to append this function to any `java.util.List` variable and it will return the size of that list( an integer). I know that list has a `size()` method. I'm just testing this out if it's possible to append a method to a class. I don't know where it doesn't really belong to.
Sample:

```
java.util.List<String> list;
list.count();
```

So even though count does not belong to java.util.List, I want this to be possible in my code. Is there any way?

edit:

It's not specifically for java.util.List only. Rather for any class. Let's say i have `Class A` and `Class B`

Now for example Class A represents a String type. And now I have a method in Class B called `length()`. I want this to be possible.

```
ClassA_VariableName.length()
```

And then I'll be able to get the length of object. Class B is like a collection of functions or features that can be appended to any type it was made to be appended to.

Comment: can you provide [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: like List<String> a;  
a.count();  
count() does not belong to List, List has size(). but i'm just trying out this "appending unbelonging method" thing. sorry i'm not very clear.

Comment: Edit your question to conform otherwise you can't really expect much help

Comment: Sorry. Quite new to StackOverflow. I did not see the edit option immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is NO, you cannot do this in Java without using introducing a new type (class or interface) that is declaring the method.

You would have to extend `java.util.List`

```
public interface SuperList extends List {

   default int count() {
      return size();
   }
}
```

And then you would have to introduce a new class that is implementing that interface (and maybe inherit stuff from an existing JDK list e.g. ArrayList).

But if you are not limited to Java you can take a look at other JVM languages. For example Groovy or Kotlin provide features to add a method to a class.

Here is an example in Groovy that uses the Expando class to add a method to a list.

```
List list = new ArrayList()

list.metaClass.count() {
    delegate.size()
}

// now call it
list.count()
```

Comment: Ohh ok ok. I'll try this. Is it a good practice to extend multiple classes?

Comment: In Java you can only extend from one class. But an interface can extend serveral other interfaces

Comment: I'd like to try this example on Groovy. Can I put your example `Class A` and then call it in `Class B` as just `list.count()` ?

Comment: Or is there a suitable design pattern that you would recommend?

Comment: In Java? No, simply don't do such a thing with Java. Use a JVM language that is good at this

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can not to add methods to classes which sources you can not change unlike javascript or ruby.

You can create your own class and inherit it from say ArrayList:

```
class MyList extends ArrayList {
    public int count() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: he wants it for any `java.util.List` not only for a specific list type

Comment: I answer that it is impossible, why this comment?